# Como puedo solucionar "403 - Forbidden" en Google Colab?

Tags: dataset, google-colab

estoy intentando descargar un data set de Kaggle en Google Colab pero me encuentro con el error **403 - Forbidden - Permission 'datasets.get' was denied**. Lei respuestas en foros, de hace vario años, diciendo que debo aceptar unos "permisos de competicion" pero nose a que se refieren.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me puede ayudar, lo agradeceria.